# infinite scroll with addthis button

Tags: ajax, scroll, addthis, infinite

I am running some tests on my page and I've inputed a infinite scroll function, witch is working fine.

The problem is that the addthis button is not loading after the 10º result till the end of the page, because this content is coming from another php. What do I need to put in my php or the .js file to get it working?

the test page is this http://hogardelocio.com/teste2.php , as you can see, the first 10 articles are perfect, scroll down the page and it will load more articles but the button doesnt show...

Please give me a step by step explanation because Im beginer in ajax world :)

Thank you

Ps: the script of the infinite scroll is this https://github.com/tournasdim/PHP-infinite-scrolling

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After you have loaded the content from your PHP script via ajax, you need to call addthis.toolbox() (in your $.ajax success callback):

```
$.ajax({
    dataType : "html" ,
    url: "jquery-loadMoreComments.php?lastComment="+ $(".postedComment:last").attr('id') ,  
    success: function(html) {
        // your existing code
        addthis.toolbox('.addthis_toolbox');
    }
};
```

This should re-render all the share buttons on the page.  I hope this works.

Update - added class name to toolbox method

Comment: it didnt worked, i've tried this addthis.toolbox() and this addthis.toolbox('#toolbox'), in this second case i've created a div id toolbox before it load the button on my php, and it shows the button just on the 1º article of the "second page", but with the wrong link when you click it.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I just tested and you need to specify the class when calling toolbox - `addthis.toolbox('.addthis_toolbox');` And make sure that you call this after you append the html.  I noticed that you called it immediately after the success callback.

Comment: yeah now I got it, Im starting to understand better these scripts :) thanks for your help